# Fancybox opening in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

My `wordpress 4` website works perfect. I use Visual composer and Magnific Popup VC Addon. 
So far so good.

My site uses a hoteliers.com that opens a `fancybox` script for reservations. I'm using the `Magnific` popup to open that but on 'check' the script opens a second `lightbox`. So in my `lightox` is an other one ;-)
Is there a way to open the check button in same target without opening second one in my popup?

Login is available and shows my 'problem'..

Comment: Could not add image, not enough reputation yet...

Comment: We would need to see the relevant html and javascript.

Comment: Is the website enough? Site is in test but login is availible

Comment: Because i use my Visual composer popup i actually don't want to use the fancybox. Cause it is already opened. The jquery.fancybox.js must open in same window/ target or not load at all then i'm there

Comment: Solved case closed...